# Linux VirtualBox Lab VLAN tagging

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, virtualbox-networking

I am in the middle of a learning experience in my network education that I’d like some community insight on. I have set up a virtual lab on my home network but am trying to add physical hosts to the lab network using an old HP ProCurve. I’m having trouble with VLAN tagging as it seems that tagged packet are not able to reach the virtual hosts. Here is a summary of my setup:

- Home network - 192.168.16.0/24, 192.168.16.1 is router
- Lab network - two subnets, 192.168.1.0/24 (Vlan 10) and
  192.168.2.0/24 (Vlan 20)
- My lab is run through VirtualBox on an Ubuntu 16.04 server at
  192.168.16.241 *(only 1 NIC)

  1. VM01 is a PFSense router and firewall; WAN interface 192.168.16.240
     and LAN int 192.168.1.1
  2. VM02 is an Ubuntu server which I would like to run DHCP and DNS; 192.168.1.5
  3. VM03 will be a DHCP host on Vlan10, 192.168.1.0
  4. I have a physical host plugged into the switch that I would like to put into Vlan10, 192.168.1.0

The switch is set up like this:

- Home router connected on port 24, untagged VLAN1
- VirtualBox server connected to port 23, untagged VLAN1, tagged VLANs 10 & 20
- Ports 1-12 untagged VLAN10 (physical host is attached to port 1)
- Ports 13-22 untagged VLAN20

I currently have all of my virtual machines’ Network configurations in VirtualBox to be using Internal Network adapter ‘intnet’ and adapter type ‘Paravirtualized Network (virtio-net).’ This is how I have been working with the VMs thus far without need of a physical switch.

I am thinking that this configuration will need to be changed to a ‘Bridged Adapter’ and the VirtualBox server configured to have a bridge interface and vlan interfaces, but I’m not exactly sure how to set this up with a single NIC. I’m assuming that eth0 must be left intact for the server to be on my home network subnet, but then a second interface on 192.168.1.0 must be set up allowing VLAN10 tagged traffic? And then how would the interfaces for the PFSense router need to be configured?

Does anyone have any tips to offer on reconfiguring the virtual lab to allow VLAN tags? Has anyone ever set up a virtual lab linked to physical hosts through switching like this?